# algorithm for 'generalized' matching in complete graphs

Tags: graph, matching, perfect

My problem is a generalization of a task solved by  [Blossom algorithm] by Edmonds. The original task is the following: given a complete graph with weighted undirected edges, find a set of edges such that

1) every vertex of the graph is adjacent to only one edge from this set (i.e. vertices are grouped into pairs)

2) sum over weights of edges in this set is minimal.

Now, I would like to modify the first goal into
1') vertices are grouped into sets of 3 vertices (or in general, d vertices), and leave condition 2) unchanged.

My questions:

1. Do you know if this 'generalised' problem has a name?
2. Do you know about an algorithm solving it in number of steps being polynomial of number of vertices (like Blossom algorithm for an original problem)? I don't see a straightforward generalisation of Blossom algorithm, as it is based on looking for augmenting paths on a graph compressed to a bipartite graph (and uses here Hungarian algorithm). But augmenting paths do not seem to point to groups of vertices different than pairs.

Best regards, 
Paweł

Comment: How are the vertices 'grouped'? How does this affect the topology of the graph?

Comment: Vertices which are connected by a path in the set of edges are 'grouped'. By condition 2), these groups are not cliques, as this would lead to an increase in sum over weights.

Comment: Every vertex in a complete graph is connected by a path, by virtue of being a connected graph. By the definition you have given, all vertices would be grouped together.

Comment: I agree with your first statement. However, I think it does not apply here: the task is to find a set of the edges which satisfy criteria 1' and 2. I would like the groups to include exactly 3 vertices, and have minimal weight -- therefore, edges _belonging to this set_ would not group all the vertices together.

Comment: Ah, I understand now - misinterpreted what 'group' implied.